# Appending a file that contains a list

Tags: python-3.x

So I am currently teaching myself python and I have the following task:
Write a python program to create a file with the numbers 1 to 10 inside.

Read this file and print the contents back to the user.

Now ask the user for a number to append to the end of the file, and append the number to the file.

Close the file.

I am okay with the first two and last part but am unsure about appending the file.

The error I get is " 'str' object has no attribute 'append'  "

I would like the user's input to be appended onto the file, but am getting an error when doing so.

Any help would be appreciated. My current code is:

```py
file1 = open("file1", "w")
r = range(10)
list1 = [*r]
file1.write(str(list1))
file1 = open("file1", "a")
a = int(input("enter the value of number: "))
file1 = open("file1", "r")
for line in file1:
    line.append(a)
    print(line)
```

Comment: for some reason i wasnt able to get my code to upload so ive added it as a comment.

Comment: file1 = open("file1","w")  ------
r = range(10) #write python program to create a file with numbers 1- 10 -------
list1 =[*r]  ------
file1.write(str(list1))   ------


file1 = open("file1", "a")  ------
a = int(input("enter the value of number"))  ------

  
file1 = open("file1", "r") ------
for line in file1: ------
    line.append(a) ------
    print(line) -------
    ive added dashes so it is easier to see the formatting

Answer (score 1):

To append to the file you will need to open with the append attribute `a+`. The `a` means open the file if it exists and start writing to the end of the file and the `+` sign tells it to create the file if it does not exist:

```
newContent = "This will be appended to the end of the file.\n"
file = open("myFile.txt", "a+")
file.write(newContent)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to append to the str you are iterating through. There is no need to iterate as you just want to append once to the end of your file. Just run the following line after opening it:

```
file1 = open("file1", "a")
file1.write(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try  using `with` for opening the file and using `a+` insted of `a`

```
`with open("file1","w") as file1:
     list1 =list[range(10)]
     file1.write(str(list1))
 with open("file1", "a+") as file1:
     a = int(input("enter the value of number"))
     file1.write(a)`
```